# I have 8GB of Free RAM, Why am I SWAPing?

Tags: swap, swap-file

I have 16GB of RAM in my iMac, right now 8GB of RAM is used... and I have 2.31GB of SWAP...

[[image: from htop[1]]

My question is, if there is 8GB of RAM still free, then why am I swapping?

Comment: [Is there a way to reduce the swappiness of OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8461/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-swappiness-of-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard) while the question is a little old the answers that it received are still applicable to the current version of macOS

Comment: In this sort of question, please always include the precise OS version ( 10.5, 10.6, 10.13 ) because the question stays around on the Internet, and may be less relevant in the future when people find it.  It's always easier in the future to google for answers.  Please consider editing your question with a few more tags and info.